# Time passing near a black hole

Tags: black-holes, time

Given distance $d$ from a normal black hole with mass $m$, how much seconds will pass at that distance while in infinite distance from the black hole $t$ seconds has passed?

Answer (score 3):

For a Schwarzschild metric you should use $\Delta s=\Delta t g_{00}$ being in this case $g_{00}=\sqrt{1-\frac{r_g}{r}}$ and $r_g=\frac{2GM}{c^2}$ the Schwarzschild radius. In your case you will put $r=d$.

Comment: Depends on whether $d$ is measured from the center or the event horizon (or some other reference point)... though the question wasn't clear on that.